# ASP Net Core Getting route values

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have the following API method in a net core 3.0 application

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/English")]
    [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/Danish")]
    //[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Transalte(string MessageId)
    {           
        //Do something based on language

        return Ok();
    }
```

Inside the controller I want to use one logic if the URL is Messages/38374/English and use another logic if I use Messages/38374/Danish.

But I don't know how to get English or Danish route value inside the controller.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separte in two Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/English")]
    public ActionResult Transalte(string MessageId)
    {           
        //Do something based on language

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/Danish")]
    public ActionResult Transalte(string MessageId)
    {           
        //Do something based on language

        return Ok();
    }
```

Separte in one Action:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/English")]
        [Route("Messages/{MessageId}/Danish")]
        public ActionResult Transalte(string MessageId)
        {
            string path = Request.Path;

            if (path.Contains("English"))
                ;//Do something based on English

            if (path.Contains("Danish"))
                ;//Do something based on Danish


            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Why insists one logic? Code reuse :) I mark the answer as correct but I expected a more elegant solution

Comment: Hi,@Luka, have you try Localization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC? https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-use-localization-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api.aspx